# Having trouble adding in php else statement

Tags: php

I'm using this php mobile detect script https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

And I have singled out this code that I want to use, however I want to throw in an 'else' option, but I seem unable to do so.

This is the code

```
<?php $check = $detect->isMobile(); if($check): ?>
   Hello you're on a phone
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is what I want to achieve

```
<?php $check = $detect->isMobile(); if($check): ?>
   You are phone 
<? else ?>
   You're something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

But when I do it throws up a Parse error: syntax error

Comment: the `else` needs a colon

Comment: A lot of down votes but no comment as to why, weird!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this simpler syntax:

```
<?php $check = $detect->isMobile(); if($check){ ?>
   You are phone 
<? } else { ?>
   You're something else
<?php } ?>
```

The above is better to understand, but you can use this too:

```
<?php $check = $detect->isMobile(); if($check): ?>
   You are phone 
<? else: ?>
   You're something else
<?php endif; ?>
```

I would rather say, **use the first part** . Though the second syntax is good, but the first is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `:` after `else` on 3rd line,

```
<?php $check = $detect->isMobile(); if($check): ?>
   You are phone 
<? else: ?> // here
   You're something else
<?php endif; ?>
```